# Why was my edit adding a resource link rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

[Link to the question that was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285617/white-space-above-logo-and-menu-bars-on-mobile-wordpress)
[Link to rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19113195)

The author shared a screenshot of his website which was not enough to work out the answer. Pictures cannot be debugged, impossibly when the website's design is complex. Websites' CSS can be debugged to a great extent using developer's tools provided in the browser. So I shared a link to **his website** in the edit, with the comment *Added necessary resource link*, the reliability of which is proved when cross-checked with the picture provided by the author.

The following reason was provided for rejection of edit:

> This edit defaces the post in order to **promote a product or service**,
>   or is deliberately destructive.

Sorry Sirs, but it's not my business to promote the author's business.

Another reason provided was:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no
>   sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

My edit was not intended to address the author, but to provide an address to the source code. My reputation is not enough to be able to comment, but it is definitely **allowed to add source-code links to questions**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first reject was probably because editing links in often looks like spam. I can't speak for the second reason.

Your edit should have been rejected anyways though. You're right that pictures are awful when asking questions, but links aren't much better; if at all. What if they change their website later? That entirely invalidates their question for future users. Questions should rely entirely on local material. Relying on external links is fragile and prone to decay.

The relevant code leading to the question should have been posted in the question itself, as text, and ideally as an MCVE.

Comment: thank you for the explanation Sir, i entirely agree that i should have posted the code itself

Comment: I think the rationale for the 2nd reject reason is the same one you're making: they should have been asking the OP to add the missing info instead of adding the link.

Answer (score 2):

> it's not my business to promote the author's business

The reviewers had no way of knowing whose site that was because the OP doesn't give the name or URL of their site in the question, comments, or even the user's profile.

Carcigenicate is right about what needed to happen for this specific question but in general when you add a link your edit summary should explain what link you're adding. "Necessary resource" isn't specific enough. You would need to say something like "Official documentation" or "GitHub repository for the plugin".